# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint Msg 2627 Cannot insert duplicate key

Tags: sql-server

I am getting a primary key violation and I don't know how to resolve it. The actual error message is;

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK_infmtx_dat_Transactions'. Cannot insert duplicate key
>   in object 'dbo.infmtx_dat_Transactions'.

My code is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO infmtx_dat_Transactions (tranid,chgid,chgidagnst,incnumagnst,rptpd,aid,claimid
,chgsvcpd,trantype,doschg,doscalpd,postdtchg,postdtchgcalpd,postdttran
,postdttrancalpd,depositdt,depositcalpd,cptid,cptcode,cptcomp,billprov
,rendprov,facid,posid,dptid,priminsmne,priminscatid,transcode,crcat
,refprovid,modalid,units,adjunits,patcnt,enccnt,cptcnt,amt,chgallow
,totworkrvu,totfacrvu,denial,curresponsible,curbal,curinsmne
,curopenbalflag,curcreditbalflag,denyflag,denycode,denydate,feetypeid )
SELECT
trn.tran_id
,trn.chg_id
,chg.chgidagnst
,chg.incnumagnst
,trn.rptpd
,trn.acctid
,chg.claimid
,chg.rptpd
,tcd.trantype
,chg.doschg
,chg.doscalpd
,chg.postdtchg
,chg.postdtchgcalpd
,trn.tranpostdt
,trn.tranpostpd
,trn.pmtdate
,trn.pmtpd
,chg.cptid
,chg.cptcode
,chg.cptcomp
,chg.billprov
,chg.rendprov
,chg.facid
,chg.posid
,chg.dptid
,chg.priminsmne
,chg.priminscatid
,trn.payermne
,tcd.crcat
,chg.refprovid
,chg.modalid
,0
,0
,0
,0
,0
,trn.trnamt
,chg.chgallow
,0
,0
,0
,''
,0
,''
,'N'
,'N'
,'N'
,''
,Null
,chg.feetypeid
FROM tmp_dat_OtherTrans trn
LEFT JOIN infmtx_dat_Transactions chg on trn.chg_id = chg.tranid AND trn.chg_id = chg.chgid
AND trn.chg_id = chg.chgidagnst 
LEFT JOIN infmtx_dic_TransCode tcd on trn.payermne = tcd.trancodemne
ORDER BY trn.tran_id;
```

How would I set a query to find the duplicate records.
The primary keys on the `infmtx_dat_Transactions` table are:tranid,chgid,chgidagnst,rptpd and trantype

Comment: What's your primary key on that table?

Answer (score 1):

The primary key (and other candidate keys) *prevent* inserting duplicate values, so you can't search for them. Duplicates don't exist.

Instead, find the primary key (and other candidate key) values in the new data you're trying to insert, and search for *them*. One of them surely duplicated in your new data, or is already in your table.

It *looks* like you could identify conflicting keys in your existing table by executing a query with an inner join between your source table "tmp_dat_OtherTrans" (including its joins) and "infmtx_dat_Transactions".

Comment: I added the inner join and it worked I did find the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH duplicate_check AS (
  SELECT 
    *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY key_column1,key_column2,key_column3 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) AS n
  FROM table_with_suspect_data
SELECT
  *
FROM duplicate_check
WHERE n > 1
```

For deleting all rows except one for each duplicate:

```
 WITH duplicate_check AS (
  SELECT 
    *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY key_column1,key_column2,key_column3 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) AS n
  FROM table_with_suspect_data
DELETE
FROM duplicate_check
WHERE n > 1
```

Comment: WITH duplicate_check AS (
  SELECT 
    *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tranid,chgid,chgidagnst,rptpd,trantype)) AS n
  FROM tmp_dat_OtherTrans
ORDER BY ROWNUMBER,tranid
SELECT
  *
FROM duplicate_check
WHERE n > 1

Comment: Using the above code I get an error Msg4112. The ranking function "ROW_NUMBER must have an ORDER BY Clause. I tried to add one but I still get the error message

Comment: Since I know that there are duplicates in my tmp_dat_OtherTrans table and this is causing my problem. I want to delete my duplicate records. I wrote the query: DELETE
FROM tmp_dat_OtherTrans 
WHERE tran_id NOT IN
(SELECT MAX(tran_id)
FROM tmp_dat_OtherTrans 
WHERE tran_id = 1187461
GROUP BY tran_id, chg_id, rptpd) what happens is the query deletes all but the three of the duplicate records. What is wrong with the query?